# Django / jQuery - Button to update a value on each row of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am just learning Django, so I am making an app that can keep track of books with a Boolean for whether I have read them or not as a learning project. The model is relatively self explanatory books have title and id and a boolean completed "field". I want to have a page that lists the books and has a button next to each book that will change the read status to True and update immediately using AJAX/jQuery (and eventually a similar unread button for mistakes). I am having trouble getting the button to work. Specifically I think I need to somehow assign some sort of id to each row so that jQuery knows which item it is working with.

Apologies for any obvious errors. I am new to web programming and I regret having to ask you all for help, but I have been trying to work out a solution myself for a few days now.

Here is the django template snippet:

```
{% for book in lib_dict.books %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ book.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ book.date_due }}</td>
    <td id="book_completed_{{ book.id }}">{{ book.completed }}</td>
    <td>
        <button id="{{ book.id }}" data-bookid="{{ book.id }}" class="btn-mini btn-primary c" type="button">Complete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```
def complete_book(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    book_id = None
    if request.method == 'GET':
    book_id = request.GET['book_id']

    if book_id:
    book = Book.objects.get(id=int(book_id))
    if book:
        book.completed = True
        book.save()

    return HttpResponse(book.completed)
```

jQuery code - I would imagine the error(s) are here

```
$('.btn-mini btn-primary c').click(function(){
    var bookid;
    bookid = $(this).attr("data-bookid");
    $.get('/libco/complete_book/', {book_id: bookid}, function(data){
        var bookstring = '#book_completed_' + bookid;
        $(bookstring).html(data);  \\trying to update the completed table cell
        $('#bookid').hide();   \\trying to hide the button
    });
});
```

Please note, all of the connectivity works fine. If I just make this button for a single row with a dedicated id, and use the appropriate #-tag in the first line of the jQuery it works, but I am having trouble with the generalization. Maybe the "." thing isn't the way to get the class in the first line?

Also, I am very much trying to teach myself, so if there are any good resources for this kind of thing please let me know. I started working on the official jQuery tutorial, but I looked through it quickly and nothing seemed too related to this.

Thanks you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('.btn-mini btn-primary c')
```

to:

```
$('.btn-mini.btn-primary.c')
```

Comment: Great, thank you! At least I was close. Also, if anyone has any good resources I would definitely appreciate the point. There are so many tutorials about it is hard to tell the ones that are worthwhile.